# Regex expression for hyphenating file name in a VS Code snippet

Tags: regex, vscode-snippets

I’m trying to create a regex for a custom VS Code snippet I’m writing. Im taking the file name that’s in camel case format and modifying it so a hyphen separates each word (before the uppercase letter) and then transforms the entire thing to lowercase. For example, if my file name was titled `myFileName`, the result would be `my-file-name`. Appreciate the help in advance!

I’m able to create the expression for hyphenating between words with `([a-z])([A-Z])/$1-$2/` but I’m not positive the if that’s the best way  to do that. After that expression I’m not able to then transform to lower case

Comment: Try using `\L` in the replacement string to convert to lowercase. `$1-\L$2`

Comment: It must be  `([a-z])([A-Z])/$1-${2:/downcase}/`

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Code snippets, the `/downcase` operator must be used to lowercase a capturing group value:

```
([a-z])([A-Z])/$1-${2:/downcase}/
```

See the [EBNF (extended Backus-Naur form) for snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar).

Comment: Thanks so much that worked and is exactly what I was looking for. Didn’t realize this but some file names have periods in them. Do you know how to accomplish this but removing the periods (or replacing with hyphen)? Thanks!

Comment: @Kate It is not that simple. You cannot use backreferences inside conditional replacement pattern, so I do not think it is possible here.